# json data after setcookie not working

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

i am facing problem while storing a json data in cookie and then accessing it. Though if i access the json data directly without storing in cookie it is working fine. But I need to store the data in cookie.

Here is my code snippet

```
var json_file = "excel_json_ip_" + myip + ".json"
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", json_file, false);
xmlHttp.send();

var jsonData = eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
    console.log(jsonData);
```

Here this variable `jsonData` stores :

```
[Object { impact=0.4, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-NPSScore", name="NPS Score", more...}, Object { impact=0.1, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Promoters", name="% Promoters", more...}, Object { impact=0, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Passives", name="% Passives", more...}, Object { impact=-0.9, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Detractors", name="% Detractors", more...}, Object { impact=1, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Reactors", name="% Reactors", more...}, Object { impact=0.5, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-XYZ", name="%XYZ", more...}, Object { impact=0.2, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-ABC", name="%ABC", more...}, Object { impact=-0.7, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-UV", name="%UV", more...}, Object { impact=0.6, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-MN", name="%MN", more...}, Object { impact=-0.4, key="NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-JKL", name="%JKL", more...}, Object { impact=-0.5, key="NPS_Telstra_Central_Question", name="* Central Question", more...}]
```

Now if I access the variable `jsonData` directly my this section of code runs fine .

```
jsonData.forEach(function(key) { 
     ####body
 })
```

But if I set the variable `jsonData` value in cookie and the access it the earlier section `foreach` does not work.

```
setCookie('jsonData', jsonData, 1); 
console.log(getCookie('jsonData'))
```

Here is in `console` I am getting :

```
 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution , I should have used the cookie value like this .

```
 var jsonDataNew = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
 setCookie('jsonData', jsonDataNew, 1);
 console.log(JSON.parse(getCookie('jsonData')))
```

`JSON.parse` the `cookie` value fixed the issue for me.